# The led doesn't switch on when button pressed and doesn't switch off when I let go off my button, what is wrong with it?

Tags: c++

This is my code I wrote for when I press the button the Led turns on , when I let go of the button then it switches off. It's always on when I press the button and always on when I let go off the button. Why is it always on?

```
    int Input_Pin = 13;
    int Out_Pin = 2;
    int Button_read;



    void setup()
    {
     pinMode(Input_Pin, INPUT);
     pinMode(Out_Pin, OUTPUT);
     Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop()
    {
     Button_read = digitalRead(Input_Pin);
     if (Button_read == 1) {
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(Out_Pin, LOW);
     Serial.println("off");
     } 
     if (Button_read == 0) {
     delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(Out_Pin, HIGH);
     Serial.println("On");  
     }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think I found an issue in your diagram...
Basically, your pin 13 is always gonna be `HIGH` because the 5V has a direct connection through it. There is nothing wrong with your code Allow me to demonstrate

[image: How the electricity flows]

The fixed circuit for this would be (The red is wrong and the blue is the fixed connection):
[image]